# Is Normal bundle on the odd-dimensional sphere trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a $2n$-dimensional oriented manifold, and $S^{2k-1}\hookrightarrow M$.

**Q**: Is the normal bundle of $S^{2k-1}$  tirvial?

Comment: Hint: think of the simplest nonorientable manfiold.

Comment: @JohnMa Sorry, I forgot to say the manifold $M$ is orientable.

Comment: The normal bundle of the diagonal of $M \times M$ is isomorphic to $TM$.

Comment: @MikeMiller So, if $M=S^{2k-1}\times S^{2k-1}$, and $S^{2k-1}\hookrightarrow M$ as the diagonal, then $N(S^{2k-1})\simeq TS^{2k-1}$, which is not trivial in general. Thanks.